# jQuery: why does $(this) within $("*") select the whole content

Tags: jquery

I do not understand this behaviour of jQuery. If I do

```
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
  });
```

Then clicking on a paragraph will cause changing its colour to red. So `$(this)` allows me to address that specific paragraph.

Now, let's say I want to do the same for *any* element on the page, so I replace `p` with `*`, as per http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp:

```
  $("*").click(function(){
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
  });
```

However now, whichever element I click, the style is changed for *all* of them. Is it a bug or do I misunderstand something? And is it possible to achieve what I want?

Here is the [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/texnic/yyvmchuf/).

Comment: CSS is cascading. So if you click on the `body` you change the color for every included element.

Comment: You should use http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't change the `color` style for all your elements. Only that which is clicked and those to which the event propagates.

**`color` is inherited** by default. When you click any element in your DOM, the event propagates to the `<body>`, the `color` style is set there and all of `<body>`s descendants inherit the style: they all become red in colour.

This would be better demonstrated by giving all elements an initial black colour:

```
* {
    color: black;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yyvmchuf/3/)

Or by changing a style that doesn't inherit it's parents by default:

```
$("*").click(function() {
    $(this).css('border-bottom', '1px solid #F00');
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yyvmchuf/4/)

> And is it possible to achieve what I want?

Yep, stop the event bubbling up the DOM tree:

```
$("*").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yyvmchuf/5/)

Comment: You got it :) This is the only reply which explained what was happening, why and how to prevent it. And it's the first answer at the same time. I've never had the answer that quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to target the clicked element:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("*").click(function(e) {
    $(e.target).css("color","red");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This one works. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLzxr70o/1/). Since you can still click on the body, it is better to use `$("body *")`

Answer (score 0):

Because `$("*")` includes body and html. If you click anywhere, you're sure to click on html. So click event is triggered on html and html(html is the whole page) is changed to red.

Answer (score 0):

`*` includes `html`, among all its content elements.

This means that if you click any element, then you are clicking the `html` element, and therefore you will effectively get `$("html").css("color","red")`. This applies the colour red to everything.

You can see evidence of this if you open up your developer tools and take a look:

[image: screenshot]

Consider this instead:

```
$("*").click(function(e) {
    $(e.target).css("color","red");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The * selector selects all elements in the document, including html, head and body.

If the * selector is used together with another element, it selects all child elements within the specified element.

Below link will give you best explanation on this.
http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Since the `*` selector applys on all elements(including `<html>` and `<body>`) then:

When you click on a `h1` you event will apply on:

- `h1`
- `body`
- `html`

The `h1` is located inside the `body` and the `body` is located inside the `html`.

Look at this [`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/sLzxr70o/) and open your console.

Now when you apply a css on your `body`, it effects all elements "under" it.

**Solution** for what you wanted:

Select all elements except for `body` and `html`:

```
$("*").not("body, html").click(function (elem) {
     $(this).css("color","red");
 });
```

[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/tmodw43q/).